# How to auto hide label after 10 sec and after label hide redirect to the ~/Default.aspx?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a label and button on label in my asp.net webform ....i want when i click on button then label1 will be visible with text "Success" and then it will hide automatically after some time say 10 seconds ,,,

I M using asp.net (VB)

How to auto hide label after 10 sec and after label hide redirect to the ~/Default.aspx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery:

```
var doRedirect = function() { location.href='http://www.example.com' };
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#label1").show();
    window.setTimeout("$('#label1').fadeOut('slow', doRedirect)", 10000);
});
```